# world needs an algorithm to find numbers summing up to the same number in a 2d square

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have been watching a TV talent show and one guy just challenged the whole
country (**!**) to solve a problem. I feel like I can write a small script to solve
it but I still need to recognize the problem somehow. So the problem goes like
this:

```
    +---+---+---+
    |   |   |   |  -->
    +---+---+---+
    |   |   |   |  -->  sum of
    +---+---+---+       3 rows
    |   |   |   |  -->
    +---+---+---+

      |   |   |     also sum of
      v   v   v     2 diagonals
       sum of
       3 columns
```

Write numbers from `1` to `9` to the squares above to get the same sum accross all
marked lines (e.g. sum of 3 rows, 3 columns and 2 diagonals).

He then continued to show the solution to this instance of the problem by
temporarily extending the big square and writing numbers in the order as:

```
        +---+
        | 3 |
    +---+---+---+
    | 2 |   | 6 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 |   | 5 |   | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
    | 4 |   | 8 |
    +---+---+---+
        | 7 |
        +---+
```

He then deleted the extra squares and placed the values in them to the
farthest empty squares respectively:

```
    +---+---+---+
    | 2 | 7 | 6 |
    +---+---+---+
    | 9 | 5 | 1 |
    +---+---+---+
    | 4 | 3 | 8 |
    +---+---+---+
```

Then he got the sums:

```
rows:
2 + 7 + 6 = 15
9 + 5 + 1 = 15
4 + 3 + 8 = 15

columns:
2 + 9 + 4 = 15
7 + 5 + 3 = 15
6 + 1 + 8 = 15

diagonals:
2 + 5 + 8 = 15
6 + 5 + 4 = 15
```

**So the problem is to solve this with a 100 by 100 square.**

1. What problem is this?
2. Is it NP complete?
3. How can I solve this?

I may be misremembering some of the details but it's not on youtube yet
so feel free to suggest changes to the problem.

**NOTE** TV is awesome

Answer (score 2):

It's called 'magic square', wikipedia gives a few examples of algorithms to generate one.

Answer (score 2):

Such squares are called MAGIC SQUARES. Read about their construction at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Method_for_constructing_a_magic_square_of_odd_order